# Echo within bash subshell

Tags: bash, echo, subshell

How do I call echo from within a bash subshell? This is behavior I want:

```
# w=5
# echo $w > /tmp/x
# cat /tmp/x
5
```

But:

```
# cmd="echo $w > /tmp/x"
# $cmd
5 > /tmp/x
```

And:

```
# $( $cmd )
bash: 5: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not `echo`.

Your problem is the redirection. You can't put redirection inside a string.

That's why you get `echo` outputting `5 > /tmp/x` in your first attempt.

The problem with your second attempt is that you "lose" the `echo` by the time the `$()` tries to run the output (because as your first attempt shows your output from `$cmd` is `5 > /tmp/x` which isn't a valid command.

That said this is [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) so stop trying to put commands in variables. It doesn't work.

Comment: I was searching for the link on wooledge.org until I realized that you all ready posted it :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback.  Incidentally, it appears that this works:  `echo $cmd | bash`

Comment: @SamirNagheenanajar No that doesn't work. It "works". Sometimes. For some inputs. In some cases. And is *still* a dangerous and bad idea. Seriously, don't do this sort of thing if you can **possibly** avoid it.